# Running shell script using Docker image

Tags: shell, docker

Input:
- There is Windows machine with Docker Toolbox installed.
- There is a shell script file `baz.sh` which calls `py2dsc-deb`.

**Problem:** `py2dsc-deb` is not available on Windows.

As I understand correctly, I can pull some Linux distro image from Docker repository, create a container and then execute shell-script file and it will run `py2dsc-deb` and do its job.

I have pulled:

```
debian - stretch-slim - 3ad21 - 3 weeks ago - 55.3MB
```

Now

1. How do I run my script using `debian`, something like: `docker exec mycontainer /path/to/test.sh`?
2. Running `docker --rm debian:stretch-slim` does nothing. Doesn't it suppose to run Debian distro at `docker-machine ip`?
3. I have tried to keep the container up using `docker run -it debian:stretch-slim /bin/bash`, then run the script using `docker exec 1ef5b ./build.sh`, but getting

> $ docker exec 745 ./build.sh
>   rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"./build.sh\": stat ./build.sh: no such file or directory"

Does it mean I can't run external script and has to always pass it inside the Docker?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute bash command inside your container by typing

```
docker exec -ti -u `username` `container_name` bash -c "cd /path/to/ && ./test.sh"
```

lets say your container name is `test_buildbox`, you are `root` and your script stays inside `/bin/test.sh` You can call this script by typing

```
docker exec -ti -u root test_buildbox bash -c "cd /bin/ && ./test.sh
```

Comment: I added an explanation with an example

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have correct line endings in your `.sh` scripts (`<LF>`) when you built Docker image on Windows.